# Salesforce AJAX API not allowing ContentVersion Create

Tags: visualforce, api, ajax

I've this code to create a Content record from AJAX toolkit api:

And when I click upload of file this is the SOAP packet that gets posted and in return I get this error:

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <se:Header xmlns:sfns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <sfns:SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>RTXBMwhZDvsm0nYhTSN.wIFaQmrW_WZW</sessionId>
        </sfns:SessionHeader>
    </se:Header>
    <se:Body>
        <create xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns1="sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <ns1:sObjects>
                <type>ContentVersion</type>
                <VersionData>DY1fDguODl8fHw4OTQxMltdDQ0K</VersionData>
                <Title>270835.txt</Title>
                <FirstPublishLocationId>05890000000YWYzAAO</FirstPublishLocationId>
                <PathOnClient>270835.txt</PathOnClient>
            </ns1:sObjects>
        </create>
    </se:Body>
</se:Envelope>
```

The error received is:

> You must specify a FirstPublishLocation where you have publish permission.

And I have already set "Library Administrator" permission to following Library ID:

```
<FirstPublishLocationId>05890000000YWYzAAO</FirstPublishLocationId>
```

Is AJAX library limited in reading Permission for selected Content Library ?

Comment: So you can manually add Content (ContentVersion) records to the Library (ContentWorkspace) via the Web UI with this user?

Comment: No. I mean if I simply have a VF page with an InputFile control and an Upload button and call Apex class function to upload ContentVersion from this user login, it uploads fine. But if I do that with javascript and AJAX Toolkit, it throws this Permission error for same code. As Shown int the SOAP Packet above, it has correct PublisherLocationId with Write Permissions and still I get error and content is not created.

Comment: thnx @JCD for correcting my SOAP xml format ...